# Special control keys in windows 7 don't work with the 'extended english keyboard (UK)' layout

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, microsoft-windows, keyboard-layout

Using gvim on Microsoft Windows, I find myself unable to use some control keys.

For example I cannot navigate the `:help` topics using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Likewise, I cannot escape insert mode using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

Do anyone know the reason for this behaviour and an possible way to have force the right behaviour?

Edit: the issue seems related to the use of the "United Kingdom (extended)" keyboard layout.

Comment: It seems to work for me in Windows. I installed Vim from the vim homepage, and used the default config.

Comment: Do you have a non-English keyboard layout? Does this also happen in a plain `gvim -N -u NONE`?

Comment: @ingo I'm using an extended english keyboard (UK). Using the given options the keys do work as intended.

Comment: Then you may have a mapping interfering. Check with `:verbose map <C-[>` and `:verbose map <C-]>` (when those don't work).

Comment: @Ingo no mapping for these unfortunately.

Comment: Too bad. Then I don't know any other way to troubleshoot than binary partitioning of your configuration: Comment out / remove half of your `~/.vimrc`, and repeat until the problem's gone. Same for used plugins.

Comment: @Ingo Oh my bad. It seems that's it's the keyboard problem. The `gvim -N -u NONE` does not change the problem (my keyboard must have change inadvertently to the normal UK I guess when I tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this; and the problem seems to be that this keyboard layout doesn't send any characters on
`<C-[>`, `<C-]>`, `<C-#>`, and `<C-\>`.

I managed to figure this out (and more importantly: fix it) by using the
[Microsoft Keyboard Layout
Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), or MSKLC for
short. You'll need to download & install it.

Here's the normal UK layout:

[image]

And here's the Extenxed UK layout:

[image]

Notice the `[`, `]`, `#`, and `\` are blank?

Now, to fix this, I did:

- Go to "File -> Load existing keyboard".
- Choose "United Kingdom Extended"
- Check the "Ctrl" checkbox on the left, and click on each of the problematic keys; filling
  in the values below that I copied from the UK keyboard layout (you need to
  click 'Advanced view' before you get to see the `Ctrl+<key>` field in the popup dialog):

  - `[` -> U+001b, scan code 1a
  - `]` -> U+001d, scan code 1b
  - `#` -> U+001c, scan code 2b (this is above the enter key)
  - `\` -> U+001c, scan code 56 (this is between the Z and left shift)

After this, I saved the "source file" (not required, I think), and went to
"Project -> Build DLL an setup package" to make a `setup.exe`; after running
this I have my "UK Extended (custom)" layout.
Strangely, this shows up as
"Welsh", and not 'English', but does seem to work. But after removing and adding it again from the
control panel, it does show up as Enlish...

Be aware that Windows has a Left-shift+Left Alt shortcut to switch keyboard layouts, which is very ease to accidentally use. And I've also experienced some special magic-fu method to automatically switch keyboard layout depending on the locale off the application. To minimize the confusion, I've always found it best to remove all keyboard layouts except the ones you really need (you can always re-add them later) (SU also has some info, [for example here](https://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows?s=1|0.0000)).

Disclaimer: I only tested this with my US-international keyboard, as I don't own a UK keyboard. But I believe this should fix your problem :-)